# Terminate a string with a semicolmn and add space VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, ascii, vb.net-2010

I have a RichTextBox which i am using to collect an array of numbers, but the numbers have to be terminated with a semicolon. I want to automatically create a space immediately after entering the semicolon and continue entering other numbers. I have tried this code but it does not create a space instead it puts the cursor at the beginning of the string:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.KeyPress
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48) _
          Or (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 59) Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 45) Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 59) Then
        RichTextBox1.Text += " "
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
        RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Help I am stuck, have tried searching on the Internet but twas fruitless

Comment: Try using the keyUp even instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx

```
If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) = 59) Then
    RichTextBox1.Text += " "
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = SelectionStart.TextLength
    RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0
End If
```

Comment: Thanx its working but its adding the space before inserting the semicolon

Comment: Change it to the KeyUp event and see what happens :)